# I would like to make a listing of happy hours in my town with Wordpress. Where to start?

Tags: wordpress

I'm thinking of creating a website that lists all the happy hours in my town with Wordpress.  I would like to create an entity for each deal, which will include fields such as "restaurant/bar name", "day of the week", "deal description".

What would be the best way to get started with something like this?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not exactly related to wordpress. So I am trying to give a general answer.

For the basics start with documented plan for the website. Then for each functionality of website , you need to either get old one or write a new plugin.